# what is ord_part in dict_col_struct for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was trying to understand a variable ord_part in the dict_col_t struct.

Here is declaration:

```
http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/include/dict0mem.h#0428
```

which says unsigned

```
 ord_part:1; /*!< nonzero if this column   appears in the ordering fields
              of an index */
```

Since it does not make sense, so I search all use cases for ord_part in the source code

```
http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/row/row0row.cc#0134

http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/row/row0row.cc#0352

http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/dict/dict0dict.cc#1949

http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/dict/dict0dict.cc#2308
```

The last link is the only place where ord_part becomes 1. When we add the index, the variable becomes 1. Based on other link, I feel that 1 indicates that we stores the prefix of the secondary key.

Anyone familiar with this variable? How does this variable works?

Comment: There are few enough "pure" programmers on this list - it's `DBA`.SE. I don't wish to appear unhelpful, but you might be better off trying the `internals` list [here](http://lists.mysql.com/) or maybe StackOverflow or possibly comp.lang.c? The programmers here are SQL ones, not C experts.

Answer (score 0):

After careful investigation of source code, here is my answer

ord_part itself does not mean anything. It will always become 1 when we add an index. If this column has an index on it, ord_part must be 1. However if ord_part is 1, it does not mean this column must have an index on it. It is MySQL bug(https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1469901).

It must work with other variables or function. When they work together,InnoDB can get actual data from the external page.

useful source code: 
   http://osxr.org/mysql/source/storage/innobase/row/row0row.cc#0058